# Why is tkinter python combobox code returning wrong output?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the second combobox `cbo_forecast_ps` to show certain values when an item in the first combobox `cbo_forecast_w` is selected.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
from ttk import *

masterframe =Tk()
# Create right frame for general information
rightFrame = Frame(masterframe,width 
=600,height=300,borderwidth=2,relief=SOLID,)
rightFrame.place(x=610,y=0)

for_w_text =StringVar()
cbo_forecast_w = ttk.Combobox (rightFrame, textvariable=for_w_text)
cbo_forecast_w['values']=("cow","chicken","ant")

string_text =StringVar()
cbo_forecast_ps = ttk.Combobox (rightFrame,textvariable=string_text)

def choosestring():
    forecast_w= for_well_text.get()
    lbl_test.configure(text = forecast_w)
    if forecast_w=="cow":
        cbo_forecast_ps['values'] = ("single")
        cbo_forecast_ps.current(0)
    else:
        cbo_forecast_ps['values'] = ("Short", "Long")
        cbo_forecast_ps.current(0)        

# I hope this is correct

cbo_forecast_w.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",choosestring())
```

What I discovered is that `forecast_w` is not taking the value from `for_well_text.get()`. Instead it was giving out `PY_VAR2`.

How to fix this?

Comment: if the answer resolve your question make sure you tick it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified version of the code you posted, the are few errors in your code you didn't create `label` to configure it and also in your comment you stated you are getting `PY_VAR2` which you are suppose to use `get` to receive the content in the `combobox`.

To receive content in the widget you can use the `for_w_text.get()` without the use of `stringvar` than you compare it just as you did and before you insert in the `cbo_forecast_ps` tin the `widget`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
from ttk import *


def choosestring(event=None):
    nf = cbo_forecast_w.get() # get the conten in the combo box

    lbl_test.configure(text = nf)  # label to configure
    if for_w_text.get()=="cow":
        cbo_forecast_ps['values'] = ("single")
        cbo_forecast_ps.current(0)
    else:
        cbo_forecast_ps['values'] = ("Short", "Long")
        cbo_forecast_ps.current(0)

# I hope this is correct


masterframe =Tk()
# Create right frame for general information
rightFrame = Frame(masterframe,width
=600,height=300,borderwidth=2,relief=SOLID,)
rightFrame.place(x=610,y=0)

for_w_text =StringVar()
cbo_forecast_w = ttk.Combobox (rightFrame, textvariable=for_w_text)
cbo_forecast_w['values']=("cow","chicken","ant")
cbo_forecast_w.pack()


string_text =StringVar()
cbo_forecast_ps = ttk.Combobox (rightFrame,textvariable=string_text)
cbo_forecast_ps.pack()


lbl_test = Label(rightFrame)
lbl_test.pack()


cbo_forecast_w.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",choosestring)

masterframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Tony Akpan  naija man run the code and if you need any assistance am there to help you.

Comment: Thanks so much @AD WAN my fellow countryman, i tried it  and it still didn't work, so what i did was to create a new button that will execute the command because the "<<comboboxselected>>" did not work. With the new button everything works fine, why the "<<comboboboxselected>>" didn't work, i have not figured that out yet. i have to continue the coding at this point.